# C# Removing Dublettes from List

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have got a list that is changing nearly every second. I want to check the list, if it gets too big. The first step will be to delete double entries from the list.

There are many ways to accomplish this. I have seen `HashTables`, `LINQ` and others. The problem is that I need a fast way to accomplish this.

There could quite a lot of entries in the list, and the user shouldn't see the application freezing, if only possible, because the application is showing an animation.

I don't know, if I can use `HashTables`, because the order of the objects inside of the list should be kept untouched, if possible.

I tried it using LINQ and GroupBy, but I am working on Visual Studio 2008, which does not contain that LINQ Statement.

The objects are not very simple. Imagine an object as a car. It can have Manufacturer, Manufacturing Time, Model Name, etc.

I want to see only if the Manufacturer and the Model Name are twice inside of the list. The manufacturing time is not important and should be ignored.

In the end I want to delete all double entries from the list.

I am happy for suggestions. If you have any ideas please just write them down and we will see.

Comment: If you want to preserve the order inside the list, there are other collection types available. SortedList and SortedDictionary come to mind. Look through the .NET collection types and see if any meet your requirements.

Comment: I have to keep the order from the entry time. If I have 3 integers in the list, it can be like this: 2,3,1. It is not sorted by value.

Comment: Ah, ok. One solution could be to use both the List and a Dictionary. It's easier to not put duplicate items in the List in the first place, than to look for them afterwards. Or you need a Dictionary to track their index as well.

Comment: This is a nice idea. Maybe I can validate the entry before adding it. If it is a duplicated entry I can just ignore it. I don't know why I did not think of that.

Comment: A (unsorted) List is not only slow when looking for items, but removing items from it is slow too. Hence the Dictionary ;)

Comment: How would I add a new object to the dictionary? I don't want to have special key-values. I just want an integer that gets incremented every time I add a new value. Also can you write an answer please so I can mark it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than delete double entries when the list gets too big, would it not be better to not allow double entries in the first place?  One way to do this is to combine your collection with an index of some sort.

The normal practice I use is to have 2 collections - one for the data and one for the index.

```
List<MyClass> _collection;
Dictionary<MyClassKey, MyClass> _index;
```

Then when I add, first I check the index and add if it's not there - otherwise don't add.

```
void Add(MyClass item)
{
    if (!_index.ContainsKey[item.Key])
    {
        _collection.Add(item);
        _index.Add(item.Key, item);
    }
}
```

This would remove the problem of deleting duplicates later and therefore no UI slowdown.

Obviously the code above is not thread safe - it's just to illustrate the point.

Comment: I do not think that is possible. I have to show data on this animation, which is coming from this list. But the data entry can vary. Sometimes there can be houndreds of objects coming in per second, sometimes only a few. If there are too many per second, the animation will just show every single one of them. Deleting dublettes makes the animation show every object just once. There are more steps to make it more performant, if deleting the duplicates is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
Sorted dictionary looks a good option.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use both the List and a Dictionary. It's easier to not put duplicate items in the List in the first place, than to look for them afterwards.

Using your Car example: to check 2 cars for equality on a subset of their properties, you need an EqualityComparer:

```
class CarComparer : IEqualityComparer<Car>
{
    public bool Equals(Car car1, Car car2) {
        return car1.Manufacturer.Equals(car2.Manufacturer)
            && car1.ModelName.Equals(car2.ModelName);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Car car) {
        return car.Manufacturer.GetHashCode() * 31 + car.ModelName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can use that to create a HashSet: (Works the same as a Dictionary, except it only holds keys instead of key/value pairs)

```
HashSet<Car> uniqueCars = new HashSet<Car>(new CarComparer());
```

Then, you can use that HashSet to check if a Car exists before you add it.

```
List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
...
if (!uniqueCars.Contains(car)) {
    uniqueCars.Add(car);
    carList.Add(car);
}
```